# How to read a file and perform a find-and-replace?

Tags: java, file, io

How would I go about going through this text file of the complete book of Huckleberry Finn and replace every occurrence of the word "the" with "a"?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Filey {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub     
       File huck = new File("HuckFinn.txt");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this simpler way in class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Filey {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner s = null;
    String meAlong="";
    PrintWriter writer = null;

    try {
        s=new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("HuckFinn.txt")));
        writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            meAlong=s.nextLine();
            meAlong=meAlong.replace("the" , "a");
            meAlong=meAlong.replace("The", "A");
            writer.println(meAlong);
        }
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (s !=null)
        {
            s.close();
            writer.close();
        }
    }

}

}
```